# Upload Excel data to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to read excel data and insert it into a SQL Server database. I am using npm package `mssql` to do the same. Also using XLSX to read Excel data.

However I keep getting the same error

> ErrorMessageToken {
> name: 'ERROR',
> event: 'errorMessage',
> number: 102,
> state: 1,
> class: 15,
> message: 'Incorrect syntax near '?'.',
> serverName: 'myservername',
> procName: '',
> lineNumber: 1 } },
> name: 'RequestError',
> number: 102,
> lineNumber: 1,
> state: 1,
> class: 15,
> serverName: 'myservername',
> procName: '',
> precedingErrors: [] }

My code:

```
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'demo.XLSX')
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filePath)
const [firstSheetName] = workbook.SheetNames
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName]

const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
    raw: true, // Use raw values (true) or formatted strings (false)
    header: 1, // Generate an array of arrays ("2D Array")
})

const pool = await connect({
    user: process.env.dbUser,
    password: process.env.dbPassword,
    server: process.env.dbServer,
    database: process.env.dbName,
    options: {
            encrypt: true,
            enableArithAbort: true,
    },
})

const query = `INSERT INTO TableName (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) VALUES ?  `
const result = await pool.request().query(query, [rows])
// also tried ...rows, [[rows]], [rows.values()]
console.log(result)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

EDIT: tried using bulk insert as well but no sucess, tried single inserts which are working fine but as soon as I move to multiple inserts, it gives an error. Any other ways I can achieve the task if this approach is not working?

Comment: You're inserting data into five columns. Have you tried using five placeholders, i.e.: `... values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`

Comment: Yes I did, but I get the same error